# Accessing resource strings from within a class with no activity

Tags: android

I have all my text names/labels defined in strings.xml.

I find that `R.string.` returns the ID reference number of the string. How do I get it to return the actual string?

```
public class ResultsFileFormat{        

    public void getAllMeasData(){

        System.out.println(" *** STRING ****" + (R.string.date));

        // File text format
        System.out.println(
        R.string.file_name + fileName + "\n" +
        R.string.date + date + "\n\n" +
        R.string.cal_table_sn + calTableSn + "\n" +
        R.string.cal_table_date + calDate + "\n" +
        R.string.cal_temp + calTemp + " C" + "\n" +
        R.string.ref_gauge + tableGaugeRef + "\n\n" +
        R.string.gauge_val_min + gauge.minGauge + "     " + tableGaugeMin + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.gauge_val_max + gauge.maxGauge + "     " + tableGaugeMax + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.groove_val_min + groove.minGroove + "     " + tableGrooveMin + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.groove_val_max + groove.maxGroove + "     " + tableGrooveMax + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.xl_min_pos + crossLevelPos.xlPosLow + "     " + xlLow + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.xl_max_pos + crossLevelPos.xlPosHigh + "     " + xlHigh + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.xl_min_neg + crossLevelNeg.xlNegLow + "     " + xlLow + " (C)" + "\n" +
        R.string.xl_max_neg + crossLevelNeg.xlNegHigh + "     " + xlHigh + " (C)" + "\n" );

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R.string.file_name will give you the id reference of that item in the R.java file. If you want to get the actual string, you need to call like this `context.getResources().getString(R.string.file_name);`. Since you are calling from a class which does not `extends Activity`, you will have to pass the context or get the application context. Pass the context using the constructor. So the final code will look like.

```
private Context context = null;
public ResultsFileFormat(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

and for getting the resource,

`String fileName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.file_name);`

I didnt run this code, please try and let me know.

Comment: Thanks your comment Bhavesth. When I try your suggestion the 'getString' is not recognised and is highlighted in red

Comment: This is good... the 'ResultsFileFormat' now shows no errors. If I want to call this function from let say the main activity, how do I pass the context to the function? ..struggling a bit with the context concept... need to read up on this.

Comment: I hope you instantiate the class `ResultsFileFormat` from the MainActivity. If so, you can pass the context through the constructor.

Say, your class `ResultsFileFormat`, has the constructor like below or create one like this. 

`public ResultsFileFormat(Context context){
     this.context = context;
}`,

Then when you instantiate your class in `MainActivity`, do as follows,

`ResultsFileFormat resultsFileFormat = new ResultsFileFormat(this);`

Here `this` means the context of the MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. I am now able to access the resource strings within my stand alone class.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use getResource method which belongs to Context Class

String filename= getResources().getString(R.string.file_name);

System.out.println(filename);

Answer (score 0):

You need instance of `Context` using which you can call `getResources().getString(R.string.<name>)`.

Use either

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
context.getResources().getString(R.string.<name>)
```

Or pass `Context` instance or Activity instance (`getActivity()` or `this`) to your java class constructor and use it to call getResources() method.